# Full row-rank submatrix of full column-rank matrix over GF(2)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $M$ be a $m$ rows and $n$ columns matrix over GF(2). And Let $M^{'}$ be a $r$ rows and $n$ columns submatrix of $M$ ($r <= m$). Note that rows of $M^{'}$ is randomly selected from $M$. Is it possible that the $M^{'}$ is full row-rank?

If it is, why?

If it is not, how about the case where $r < m$?

Edit:

1) I forgot to mention $m > n$.

2) I have run some experiments on Matlab. In experiments, I first randomly generated $10^{6}$ matrices over GF(2). Each matrix has $m = 288$ rows and $n = 216$ columns. Turn out they all have the rank of $216$. Then, I randomly generated $10^{6}$ matrices over GF(2). Each matrix has $m = 84$ rows and $n = 216$ columns. Turn out they all have the rank of $84$. So I am very confused now.

Comment: If an $m\times n$  $(m\geq n)$ matrix has i.i.d elements with 50% probablity 1 and 50% probablity 0, the probability for it to be of full rank (i.e. rank $n$) is $\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac {2^m-2^k}{2^m}$. As this result is forklore, I would vote to close the problem unless you can provide more details about the problem.

Comment: Sorry, why it is forklore?

Comment: The columns of a full-rank matrix are linearly independent. Taking them as vectors, the first vector can not be $0$, the second vector can not lie in the linear space spanned by the first vector, the third vector can not lie in the linear space spanned by the first and second vector, etc.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your answer. Can you write your comments above as an answer to this question? So I can click an upvote, or the accept to show my appreciation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a formula to compute the probablity of an $m×n$ $(m≥n)$ matrix to be of full rank: if the matrix has i.i.d uniformly distributed elements drawn from $\{0,1\}$, the probability for it to be of full rank (i.e. rank n) is $∏^{n−1}_{k=0}\frac{2^m−2^k}{2^m}$.

The formula can be proved by induction: Take the columns of a full-rank matrix as linearly-independent vectors. For $n=0$, the matrix is full-rank iff not all elements are $0$, so the formula holds.

Assume the formula holds for $n=k$. The $(k+1)$th vector should not lie in the linear space spanned by the first $k$ vectors, so the number of possibilities for the $(k+1)$th vector to be independent with the previous vectors is $2^m-2^k$. As there're $2^m$ $m$-dimensional vectors in $\text{GF(2)}$, we should append a term $\frac{2^m-2^k}{2^m}$, so the formula holds for $n=k+1$.

Hope this answers your question.